# How to retain my current css if i use bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to use `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>`
but to do it i need to put a bootstrap below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

the problem is, my current table and some h1 text is changing the size or design if I put that bootstrap, what should I do? Any idea?

The resut is on this picture
[With Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JepW.png) the icon of gly is working
but this is my default and i want the size of this table [Without Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbpw.png)

my css is here

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  
}
body{
    
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background:  linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(66, 183, 245, 0.8) 0%, rgba(66, 245, 189, 0.4) 100%);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}
.tbl-header{
  position: relative; 
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
   top: -45px;
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
    
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
   background:  black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}



@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);

section{
  margin: 50px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}


*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a, a:visited, a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  position: relative; 
  top: -40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.92em;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -0.055em;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 48px;
    color: #03e9f4;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px black;
  
}
h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 60px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: -0.015em;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: calc(75px + 2vh + 2vw) auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 840px;
}
.search-box {
  top: -40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.search-box1 {
 top: -60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;    
}
input[type="text"]{ padding: 10px 10px; line-height: 5px; }

.search-icon, .go-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 86px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
}
.search-icon {
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 1.22em;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center center;
  -o-transform-origin: center center;
  transition: transform 400ms 220ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition: transform 400ms 220ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: transform 400ms 220ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -o-transition: transform 400ms 220ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}
.si-rotate {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.go-icon {
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 1.38em;
  will-change: opacity;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -o-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}
.go-in {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(0);
  transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms 20ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms 20ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms 20ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -o-transition: opacity 190ms ease-out, transform 260ms 20ms cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}
.search-border {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 60px;
}
.border {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.border {
  stroke-dasharray: 740;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 400ms cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.735, 0.990);
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 400ms cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.735, 0.990);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 400ms cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.735, 0.990);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 400ms cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.735, 0.990);
}
.border-searching .border {
  stroke-dasharray: 740;
  stroke-dashoffset: 459;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 650ms cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.150, 0.205, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 650ms cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.150, 0.205, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 650ms cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.150, 0.205, 1.000);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 650ms cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.150, 0.205, 1.000);
}
#search {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  padding: 0 68px 0 68px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.32em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -0.015em;
  outline: none;
  color:black;
}
#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #FFFFFF;}
#search::-moz-placeholder {color: #FFFFFF;}
#search:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #FFFFFF;}
#search:-moz-placeholder {color: #FFFFFF;}
#search::-moz-selection {color: #FFFFFF; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);}
#search::selection {color: #FFFFFF; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);}

.submit-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.submit-btn:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Link your CSS below the bootstrap CSS, this will give your CSS an edge over bootstrap.

Comment: @RitikBanger No, that's not true! Browsers follows the [**Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules and the order of the stylesheets doesn't matter even if it seems to be in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

***Generally speaking,***

*If your CSS comes after Bootstrap's, then Bootstrap is given priority and will override your CSS where possible.*

*If your CSS comes after Boostrap's, then in some cases, your CSS will be given priority.*

**Additionally,** if you're planning to work with Bootstrap then being mindful of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) moving forward can save you some headache. Plus, when all else fails and you are sure the issue is a clash between your CSS and Bootstrap then you can take a look at how that CSS rule is declared in Bootstrap CSS and that will likely give you some hint as to how to circumvent it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just follow this pattern when you linked the bootstrap css and your custom css file to the head section.

Link bootstrap css first

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then link your custom css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```